# C++ multiple interfaces that only differ in return type?

Tags: c#, c++, templates, interface, overloading

Doing an experiment of translating .NET IL to C++ in a human readable fashion.

**Here is the issue:** C# allows you to resolve multiple interfaces with the same method name that only differ in return type. C++ doesn't seem to support this however making resolving two interfaces impossible using the vTable (or am i wrong?).

I've found a way to replicate the C# approach in C++ using templates but **am wondering if there is a way that doesn't require templates that solves the same issue?** Templates are verbose and I'd prefer not using them for every interface type if possible.

**Here is the C++ version.**

```
template<typename T>
class IMyInterface
{
    public: short (T::*Foo_IMyInterface)() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class IMyInterface2
{
    public: int (T::*Foo_IMyInterface2)() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public IMyInterface<MyClass>, public IMyInterface2<MyClass>
{
    public: MyClass()
    {
        Foo_IMyInterface = &MyClass::Foo;
        Foo_IMyInterface2 = &MyClass::IMyInterface2_Foo;
    }

    public: virtual short Foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private: int IMyInterface2_Foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass
{
    public: virtual short Foo() override
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

void InvokeFoo(IMyInterface<MyClass>* k)
{
    (((MyClass*)k)->*k->Foo_IMyInterface)();
}

void main()
{
    auto a = new MyClass2();
    InvokeFoo(a);
}
```

**Here is the C# reference source the C++ one is based on.**

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    short Foo();
}

interface IMyInterface2
{
    int Foo();
}

class MyClass : IMyInterface, IMyInterface2
{
    public virtual short Foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int IMyInterface2.Foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    public override short Foo()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

namespace CSTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void InvokeFoo(IMyInterface k)
        {
            k.Foo();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new MyClass2();
            InvokeFoo(a);
        }
    }
}
```

This C++ method **doesn't work below** but wish it did (its more what I'm going for).

```
class IMyInterface
{
    public: virtual short Foo() = 0;
};

class IMyInterface2
{
    public: virtual int Foo() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public IMyInterface, public IMyInterface2
{
    public: virtual short Foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private: int IMyInterface2::Foo()// compiler error
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass
{
    public: virtual short Foo() override
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

void InvokeFoo(IMyInterface* k)
{
    k->Foo();
}

void main()
{
    auto a = new MyClass2();
    InvokeFoo(a);
}
```

Comment: Your interface class isn't really an interface since it isn't virtual and set to 0.

Comment: Yes I know (I can't in C++ is the issue). If I do that I get compiler errors in C++ as C++ has no way to resolve two base classes with the same method signature that only differs in return type like C# does.

Comment: Looks like you might not be allowed to only change the return type when overloading: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Comment: I. e. you are looking for something like `class MyClass { short IMyInterface::foo() override; int IMyInterface2::foo() override; }`? Maybe we should propose this for C++20 or later?

Comment: @fstam That's not the issue here - we inherit in `MyClass` both `short IMyInterface::foo()` *and* `int IMyInterface2::foo()` and can both use legally (although needing appropriate qualification). Problem is: we cannot *override* as we cannot specify *which one* to override...

Comment: @Aconcagua Isn't that caused by the overloading issue?

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes you're correct. If C++20 supported something like this similar to how the C# interface example does, would be useful. C++ is a multi inheritance lang and this example does (to me) very much fit into what I would expect possible in C++.

Comment: @fstam Hm, at a closer look - you might be right... At first, it seems only somewhat related, but still different - derived class `C` *can* inherit two different versions of `foo` (same signature, different return type) from both `A` (assuming `void`) and `B` (assuming `int`). Solely, we cannot just write `C c; c.foo();`, as call is ambigous, we need to write `c.A::foo(); int n = c.B::foo();`. But now trying to override `A::foo` apparently creates an (*invalid*) overload for `B::foo` (or vice versa) - *if* the term 'overload' is correct in this specific scenario, not entirely sure about...

Comment: @Aconcagua Was able to find it on stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807840/is-it-possible-to-have-different-return-types-for-a-overloaded-method/25617253 and even more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type

Comment: @fstam Following links from cited question, there's a more interesting [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/442026/1312382), but both don't fully cover the case here. The interesting question is: *When* do we create overloads? Just inheriting two versions of `foo` (`A::foo` and `B::foo`) cannot be considered 'overloading', as if it was, compiler would need to refuse if both differ only in return type - but it does not. Now overriding one of these two `foo` versions (i. e. exchange the function pointer in vtable) - is this at the same time overloading the other one? *Seems* so, at least.

Comment: @Aconcagua Look at it from the perspective of the object we are creating. If you inherit only one `foo`, the object inheriting isn't overloading, it contains only a single definition of `foo`. If you then go and inherit the other `foo`, the object in question IS overloading and now has 2 definitions of `foo`. This is when we overload. How this works in the vtable I wouldn't know. I'm a C# developer so I guess take all this with a grain of salt :)

Comment: @fstam Ha, in C# you have vtables, too. It's de-facto standard when implementing polymorphism. Solely, people speak of much less than with C++... We're getting at the point where we need to define what overloading actually is (well, we should look up how standard defines!). If it mandatorily prohibits overloads only differing in return type, such inheritance *cannot* be overloading. Additionally, overloads cannot be select via scope resolution (`c.C::bar();` - which one, if I have two?), but inherited functions *can* (`c.A::foo`, `c.B::foo`, but call is not virtual any more).

Comment: @Aconcagua I just tried it in C#. You *can't* inherit both definitions of `foo` in a class without explicitly saying what interface they come from (called an `explicit interface implementation`). `Explicit interface implementations` can't be `public`. It does allow you to not-implicitly define one of the foo definitions, you can make that public. This way to object only ever exposes either of the foo's. If you try the same without inheritance in the mix you get the following error: `Type 'testclass' already defines a member called 'bar' with the same parameter types
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186745/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-fstam).

Comment: As a side note C++/CLI support something similar to C# for managed code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536808/c-cli-explicit-implementation-of-interface-overrides.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you can't overload based on return type alone.

See

- [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm)
- [Is it possible to have different return types for a overloaded method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807840/is-it-possible-to-have-different-return-types-for-a-overloaded-method/25617253)
- [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

The last stackoverflow thread points out overloading is possible using operators.

```
struct func {
    operator string() { return "1"; }
    operator int() { return 2; }
};

int main() {
    int x = func(); // calls int version
    string y = func(); // calls string version
    double d = func(); // calls int version
    cout << func() << endl; // calls int version
    func(); // calls neither
}
```

You can't name them though, this would quickly turn into a mess to work with.

The argument list has to change. Victor Padureau suggested to use void return types and pass the type of value as reference to be set to a value in the method, that will work. You can also change the method name for the different types.

```
class my_interface
{
public: 
    virtual short foo_short() = 0;
};

class my_interface2
{
public: 
    virtual int foo_int() = 0;
};

class my_class : public my_interface, public my_interface2
{
public: 
    short foo_short() override
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int foo_int() override
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class my_class2 : public my_class
{
public: 
    virtual short foo_short() override
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

void InvokeFoo(my_interface* k)
{
    short result = k->foo_short();
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}

void main()
{
    auto a = new my_class2();
    InvokeFoo(a);
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea as it would solve all situations C# supports. Would make the end result verbose but does work. 99% of code doesn't run into this example issue which is the down side name mangling for the 1% but might be best.

Comment: @zezba9000 I think the references approach is fine too, less verbose. It's really about clarity at this point, what's most readable, nicest to work with, etc. Very much personal preference.

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't have considered different cast operators overloads - instead, I'd consider `operator X()` and `operator Y()` just as different as `void foo()` and `void bar()` functions...

Comment: @Aconcagua I guess they are that different. I wouldn't use it, what happens when you use those operators with auto? Plus the issue remains that you can't put the definitions in sepperate structs (they are in the same struct in the example) and inherit them. You still run into the same overloading issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution that might work. It's not perfect, but it is a way to workaround the issue if you are porting.

Instead of calling `int foo()` you can call `void foo(int& out)` that way you are putting the return type in the calling part of the function.

Comment: Hmm interesting as that does compile and fix the issue. Not sure if thats better vs templates though (might be). Will keep this in mind for what direction to take for sure.

Comment: @zezba9000 At least, you do not have to write your own vtables (which is what your templates effectively do...).

Comment: Would prevent code like `bar(foo());`, though, we'd get forced to use an intermediate variable - if the former is 'good style' at all, well another issue...

Answer (score 1):

Best is: [not having the same function names in both interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194490/1312382), [making return values output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194421/1312382) certainly is an interesting alternative. For completeness: let's assume we cannot change the base classes' interfaces, perhaps because of coming from different libraries – and we still need to override.

Well, first: Inheriting both interfaces at all might be a questionable design, it is very likely that you'll be violating the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Now let's assume we need to anyway. A possible workaround  then (it doesn't match my own definition of 'elegance' – but at least...) are intermediate classes:

```
class BaseA { virtual ~BaseA(); virtual void foo(); };
class BaseB { virtual ~BaseB(); virtual int foo(); };

class DerivedA : public BaseA { void foo() override; };
class DerivedB : public BaseB { int foo() override; };

class Derived : public DerivedA, public DerivedB { };
```

Now `Derived` can serve as both `BaseA` *and* `BaseB` and still has overridden both (in this case) variants of foo, albeit indirectly.

If you intend to further inherit from `Derived`, still allowing to override either variant of `foo` function, then each override in `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` would itself call a (new) virtual function `fooA` and `fooB` respectively:

```
class DerivedA : public BaseA
{
public:
    void foo() final // better than override:
                     // prevents breaking the pattern again
    { fooA() };
protected:
    virtual void fooA() = 0;
};
class DerivedB : public BaseB
{
public:
    int foo() final { return fooB() };
protected:
    virtual int fooB() = 0;
};
```

This same trick allows the overrides to use members of both bases and is certainly the *cleanest* approach to get the matter done, however, it comes with some tradeoff as virtual function calls don't come for free (vtable lookup, then actual function call) – so if performance is more important (think well if it *really* is!), you might just implement the overrides in `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` directly.

Comment: If one intend to derive classes from `Derived` and want to override either `foo`, then usually `DerivedA::foo` would call virtual `foo_A` method (same for B) and subsequent derivation would use and override `foo_A` or `foo_B`

Answer (score 0):

If you want C++ code that would essentially be similar to your C# example, I would recommend you to essentially add an extra intermediate class `MyClass_IMyInterface2` with the sole purpose to rename methods that are implemented explicitly in C# code.

Thus you would have something like:

```
class IMyInterface2
{
public: 
    virtual int Foo() = 0;
};

class MyClass_IMyInterface2 : public IMyInterface2
{
protected:
    int Foo() final { return IMyInterface2_Foo(); }
    virtual int IMyInterface2_Foo() = 0; 
};

class MyClass : public IMyInterface, public MyClass_IMyInterface2...
```

By the way, you only need to add the extra class if you have conflicts and only need to do the renaming if so.

Assuming that the purpose would be to mimic C# code, I would probably do it each time an interface method is explicitly implemented.

You could also adjust the visibility of the members as desired.